# Outlook calendar disappear from inbox after accept the request

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

Outlook 2010 and 2010+ versions seem to remove meeting request emails from your inbox once you accept or decline the invite.

How do I prevent these from being removed and keep them in my inbox?

Usually the meeting invite also contains useful information or things that need to be followed up later.

Comment: Usually, the email text gets saved into the calender item, so you can just check the corresponding calender entry (double click on it) and the info should be there.

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't solve the problem on a Mac. I don't have 'Options' in my File menu.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Outlook, this is found under the **File** tab. Click **Options**, then **Mail**, and scroll down to the **Send messages** section.  Uncheck the box next to **Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding**

Comment: Thanks for putting it as an answer on stackoverflow.. i appreciate it.

Comment: how does one do this through the web UI?

Comment: The checkbox is currently in the following location on the web UI: Settings -> Mail -> Calendar -> Automatic Processing -> Invitations.

Answer (score 4):

The provided "ounce of prevention" instructions are spot on!  However, when faced with the immediate dilemma of needing the email... one goes to the *Deleted Items* folder to find the email, BUT (because the invitation email may be prevented from opening by Outlook) one must click *Reply* to then be able to once again read (and hyperlink-click) the original email entries.

Answer (score 4):

I just did this, but with the **Outlook web (Office 365)** it's a little different now. To stop calendar invites being deleted do the following:
Go to the settings wheel > View all Outlook settings > Calendar > Events and invitations > uncheck the box 'delete invitations and responses that have been updated'

Comment: These updated instructions are helpful, though they appear applicable only to Outlook 365 Enterprise on the web (not personal Outlook). However, in my case the check box simply doesn't work. I've had that box unchecked for months, but every time I accept or decline an invitation from the Inbox, it either goes straight to the Deleted Items folder or it vanishes completely.

Comment: Useful update to a good answer. It is a bit unbelievable that this would be the default behavior and that one has to ask/search SO to find the setting, buried five clicks deep. Par for the course with a Microsoft product, I guess.

Comment: Turns out this checkbox is completely ignored unless you use Outlook app or web interface. Still no support from MS. What a joke.

Comment: As of today there is only "Delete invitations that have been updated by the organiser" which seems to be something different and doesn't work for this